# Migrate AWS DynamoDB to Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, apache-spark, migration, amazon-dynamodb

I have a production DynamoDB with around 20GB of data. I need to migrate these data to PostgreSQL with **zero downtime**. The DynamoDB have **100-300s of write request per second** so that zero downtime is very important. I couldn't find any reference to the exact problem but got **kind of a solution with AWS EMR and Apache Spark-Stream**(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-your-data-on-amazon-dynamodb-with-apache-spark/). But I'm not fully confident with that because its something related to HadoopRDD and I'm a NodeJS guy. Anyone have a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need to switch over the writes to the new database first, but query from both for a while. Then copy the old data over (careful to not overwrite anything that has already been updated in the meantime). When that is done, switch off the old read path. But 20GB is rather small. Cannot take a small maintenance window (putting the database into read-only for the migration if you cannot offline it completely)?

Comment: @Thilo, What about the steps backwards, first copy old data to new DB and then apply each write operation one by one to new DB. I think using the DynamoDB Streams can stream operations one by one?

Comment: Yes, that should work, too. Moves the problem to the other end --- you want to start replaying the stream from the point of time immediately after the snapshot backup. And once the replica has caught up, you can switch over the writes to the new database.

Comment: @Thilo, do you have any sample code snippets or something like that using apache spark? If so it will be grateful.

Comment: Hi I have the same problem but not exactly, I have a huge data in dynamodb and I need to migrate to postgres. how can I do it? Any software to map and migrate data automatically?